# Set the active Navigation Menu from a plugin

Tags: plugins, menus, navigation, options

Is there a way to set the following option from a WordPress plugin, if you know the name of the menu you want to set:
[image]

My developer says it's not possible, but I am sure on of you gurus knows a way around this ;)

Comment: If you could configure everything theme i wonder why you are looking for a plugin !

Comment: It's certainly possible to customize this, but plugin recommendations are off-topic on this site.

Comment: It's not about what plugin to use for this. I am developing a plugin, which imports pages and menus created in another app. I want to activate the imported menu directly from my plugin, so the user does not need to change it manually.

Comment: Paul, you will need to post the code you are trying to use to do this, even if that code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `wp_nav_menu_args` filter ( [Codex reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_nav_menu_args) ) to set a theme location to use a specific menu.

**Example:**

```
function test_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
    // only set menu for the primary navigation menu.
    if ( $args['theme_location'] != 'primary' ) {
        return $args;
    }
    // change {main-menu} to be the slug of the menu you want to set.
    $args['menu'] = 'main-menu';
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'test_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_theme_mod`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod) and [`set_theme_mod`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_theme_mod) to save nav menu locations.

Get locations:

```
$locations = get_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations' );
var_dump( $locations );
```

prints:

```
Array
(
    [primary] => 0
    [secondary] => 0
)
```

Get existing nav menus:

```
$nav_menus = get_terms( 'nav_menu', array( 'hide_empty' => true ) );
var_dump( $nav_menus );
```

prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 2
            [name] => Main
            [slug] => main
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 2
            [taxonomy] => nav_menu
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 3
        )
}
```

Set location:

```
$nav_menu_id = $nav_menus[0]->term_id;
$location = 'primary';
$locations[ $location ] = $nav_menu_id;
set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', $locations );
```